# Find three types of function .

Tags: limits, continuity

If [image]  be a continuous function
at $x = 1$, we have to find the value of $4g (1) + 2 f (1) – h (1)$. Assuming that $f (x)$ and $h (x)$ are continuous at $x = 1$.�

I try alot but not getting any start .

Could anybody help me in this.

Comment: Is the answer 5?

Comment: @MattG88 yes the answer is 5  ,but how

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain it briefly. For a function,say $f(x)$, to be continuous at $x=a$,

$f(a$<sup>-</sup>$)=f(a)=f(a$<sup>+</sup>$)$

So, here, investigate $g(x)$ at $x=1$<sup>+</sup>,$1$<sup>-</sup> which gives two equations using the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1^+)^n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1^-)^n$ = 0

$g(1^-)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1^-)^nf(1^-) +h(1^-)+1}{2(1^-)^n+3(1^-)+3}$ , $g(1^+)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1^+)^nf(1^+) +h(1^+)+1}{2(1^+)^n+3(1^+)+3}$

Since the functions are continous at $x=1$, we get

$6g(1)=h(1)+1$ and $2g(1)=f(1)$
So, required result becomes $2g(1)+1$

Also, $\lim_{x \to 1}2^x=2$ which makes $g(1)$ limit indeterminate$(\frac{0}{0})$. So, we take derivates for both numerator and denominator which gives $g(1)=\lim_{x \to 1}2cos^2(2^x\pi)=2$. So, the required answer is 5.

PS: If you don't understand how to solve basic indeterminate forms, I think you should start with that.

Comment: How do you get the result 2g(1) + 1

Comment: $h(1)=6g(1)-1$, $f(1)=2g(1)$, replace them in $4g(1)+2f(1)-h(1)$ and you'll get $2g(1)+1$